# Is it really required to use express or other framework with node.js?

Tags: php, node.js

I am a new learner to node. I am getting some issues with node. Like if it is really required to use any framework/module like 'Express' etc with node?
Cant we just simply create a web application similar to PHP or asp etc. In PHP we can simply create files & we know where to put our files & rest of the things handled by server itself.

**PHP Frameworks** : CodeIgniter, CakePHP  (Tell us where to put code, means MVC etc)
**Node Frameworks** : Express , Fab.js (Tell us without using these we cant proceed easily)

For example i want to create a simple Profile edit form for a student. In php i can simply create a form in HTML, display already filled values by user in fields & can add some validations on it. But with node,how we can do it?

- Where actually should i place my server side files?
- Do i really require any framework(express) to do that in node?
- Can i write a mixture of html & Node.js together as we usually do in PHP using < ?php ?>

Comment: Your PHP scripts are typically invoked by an Apache module, and most of the HTTP processing infrastructure is baked into Apache and PHP itself. With NodeJS, you're just writing programs to run on some server, so you need some way of reading data from a TCP socket, HTTP protocol processing, some nice API which allows you to build your routing and access the headers sent by the browser in some meaningful form, etc. etc. Express is meant to be a reusable solution to these problems. If you want to build all of that yourself, more power to you.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, `express` is what in ol' php world might be apache+php_plugin - just for node/js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Like if it is really required to use any framework/module like 'Express' etc with node?

No. As with any framework, it just makes life easier for you by doing some common things for you.

> In PHP we can simply create files & we know where to put our files & rest of the things handled by server itself.

Typical Node apps have the server built in and have to do URL routing themselves (this is what Express does).

Typical (small) PHP apps use a separate server and let it handle their routing for them.

You can do that with Node, but you need to have some way to link the server to the specific JavaScript program you want to run. You could write all your JavaScript programs to conform with the CGI specification, but CGI isn't very efficient and (my impression is that) most people choosing to use Node do so for performance reasons.

> Where actually should i place my server side files?

This is up to you. There are lots of approaches you can take to organise your code.

> Can i write a mixture of html & Node.js together as we usually do in PHP using `< ?php ?>`

PHP makes it easy to mix your business logic with your display logic. This makes it very easy to knock out trivial programs. It also makes it very easy to make non-trivial programs a maintenance nightmare.

As far as I know, Node doesn't come with a templating language but plenty are available through NPM. I'm not aware of any that let you splurge raw JavaScript into the middle of templates, but that isn't a feature I'd consider desirable.

Answer (score 1):

- you can put your node files anywhere, it's common to have the main entry point to your app at root level of your project.  Then libraries generally are out in a subdirectory, 3rd party modules are managed through npm and install to node_modules by default.  node_modules is on node path by default so they can be referenced without paths ie require('async'), assuming you have installed npm async
- you don't need any framework, node provides all the tools necessary to create a server in its standard library
- node has a couple of templating libraries, I'm pretty sure most of them allow you to mix html and a couple of expressions that evaluate to js, like loops and conditionals. Some might allow arbitrary js, but I don't have any experience with them